# No request delivery notification has been received from LSAPI application, possible dead lock

Tags: openlitespeed

I am using OpenLiteSpeed 1.7.16 Server, and I am getting the following error sometimes in the log viewer of LS Admin Panel.

```
No request delivery notification has been received from LSAPI application, possible dead lock
```

Site getting completely slow while happening this. I tried checking the HTOP in the terminal to check any kind of unusual CPU hike but nothing. The site completely made up with PHP.

How to solve this issue?